# GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\ClientException: Client error: `POST resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:\n{"@context":"\\/api\\/contexts

Tags: php, api-platform.com, symfony5

I have built an API endpoint using this tutorial https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform. I have tested the API from the web interface and it accepts the input and stores the data. Now I am trying to send data from my application to the endpoint.

```
 curl -X POST "https://myweblocation.app/api/emergencyvisits" -H "accept: application/ld+json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"externalpatientid\":\"<patient-id>\",\"externalsiteid\":\"<site-id>\",\"poscode\":20,\"dos\":\"2020-02-28T00:10:52.416Z\",\"vistreason\":\"chest hurting bad\"}"
```

My code is this:

```
    $client = new Client(['verify' => 'my/pem/location.pem' ]);
    $siteid = $GLOBALS['unique_installation_id'];

    $body = [
        'externalpatientid' => $uuid,
        'externalsiteid' => $siteid,
        'poscode' => $pos_code,
        'dos' => $date,
        'visitreason' => $reason
    ];

    $headers = [
    'content-type' => 'application/json',
        'accept' => 'application/ld+json'
    ];

    $request = new Request('POST', 'https://myweblocation.app/api/emergencyvisits', $headers, json_encode($body));

    $response = $client->send($request, ['timeout' => 2]);
```

How to get Guzzle to programmatically produce the correct post to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, please don't post sensitive data like patient-id, site-id or your application URL.

Regarding your problem...
In your curl command you use the param name `vistreason` but in your Guzzle request you use `visitreason`.

I've tested that with Postman and it returned a 500 Server error because the field `vistreason` can't be null.

Beside this I tested with Guzzle (6.x):

```php
$client = new Client(['verify' => false]); // I deactivated ssl verification
$body = [
    'externalpatientid' => '<id from curl request>',
    'externalsiteid' => '<id from curl request>',
    'poscode' => 20,
    'dos' => '2020-02-28T00:10:52.416Z',
    'vistreason' => 'chest hurting bad'
];

$response = $client->request(
    'POST',
    '<your-server-api-url>',
    [
        'headers' => [
            'content-type' => 'application/json',
            'accept' => 'application/ld+json'
        ],
        'body' => json_encode($body),
    ]
);

var_dump(json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents()));
// Output seems to be a valid response with some data from the request.
```

Maybe there is something wrong with your cert for validation.

*Note:* I also highly recommend to implement a authentication in form of a token to interact with your API!

Comment: I will implement a token once I have basic communication working.

Comment: It ended up being that my poscode was being sent to the server as a string and not an int. After I learned how to use the Symfony profiler. I was able to see all the errors and the code had been working for a while. That was the only problem.